# Why are moments necessary in Variance Shadow Map

Tags: shader, shadow

[This article](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/gpu-gems-3-chapter-8-summed-area-variance-shadow-maps) describes how to render shadows with Variance Shadow Maps.

It says that when rendering the scene into the shadow map, you should store the depth and the depth squared(adjusted for biasing using partial derivatives).

```
float2 ComputeMoments(float Depth)
{
    float2 Moments;
    // First moment is the depth itself.
    Moments.x = Depth;
    // Compute partial derivatives of depth.
    float dx = ddx(Depth);
    float dy = ddy(Depth);
    // Compute second moment over the pixel extents.
    Moments.y = Depth*Depth + 0.25*(dx*dx + dy*dy);
    return Moments;
}
```

You then check your depths against the shadow map like this:

```
   float ChebyshevUpperBound(float2 Moments, float t)
   {
       // One-tailed inequality valid if t > Moments.x
       float p = (t <= Moments.x);
       // Compute variance.
       float Variance = Moments.y – (Moments.x*Moments.x);
       Variance = max(Variance, g_MinVariance);
       // Compute probabilistic upper bound.
       float d = t – Moments.x;
       float p_max = Variance / (Variance + d*d);
       return max(p, p_max);
    }

    float ShadowContribution(float2 LightTexCoord, float DistanceToLight)
    {
        // Read the moments from the variance shadow map.
        float2 Moments = texShadow.Sample(ShadowSampler, LightTexCoord).xy;
        // Compute the Chebyshev upper bound.
        return ChebyshevUpperBound(Moments, DistanceToLight);
    }
```

The article then says that you may be able to get away with not biasing the depth squared at all, just make sure to clamp the variance to a minimum value. In the source code that comes with the book, the code that calculates the bias is commented out and it says just to clamp to a minimum variance.

So why even store the depth squared in the first place? And further, why not skip the calculation of the variance, and just always use the minimum variance? If moment 1 is the depth and moment 2 is the depth squared, shouldn't the variance always come out to 0?

```
float Variance = Moments.y – (Moments.x*Moments.x);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't filter the texture, this would be true, but the main idea of this type of shadow map is that it can be linearly filtered. Filtered(depth^2) is not equal to filtered(depth)^2. This is where the variance comes from.

Many thanks to the author for clearing this up.